# Implement a key-value deserialization or something similar

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh, database

I'm wondering how to best implement a parameter `$x`, say `$7` – I mean a last parameter to a parameter-rich function – that would serve as "put various key-data things here to stop adding more parameters"? Possible call could be: `afunction param1 param2 ... "MYDATA=1 OTHERDATA=true"`. It's that I need to pass bunch of simple marks on some data to a function and don't need reserved positional parameters for them, especially because some of the marks are
optional and cannot be assigned to a fixed position in function's signature.

**UPDATE:**
Example Zsh solution could be: `afunc ...normal parameters... "MYDATA:1:OTHERDATA:2:"` and then: `local mydata="${7/(#b)*MYDATA:([^:]#):*/$match[1]}"`. I could write a function to hide the complex pattern code, it would work like: `get_key "$7" "MYDATA"; local mydata=$REPLY`. That solution works but I really want to research this and find solution that's best or useful in a specific way.

Comment: Why did you tag both `bash` and `zsh` which use different scripting languages?  Which one do you want to use?

Comment: @JuliePelletier: both Bash and Zsh people can answer, I'll adapt Bash code to my needed Zsh code, you have to admit that tagging "zsh" would exclude many experts

Comment: I disagree and I also mean that you should say what you really want.  If you were able to adapt the solution, you wouldn't ask for help.

Comment: @JuliePelletier: it's about general shell limitations and coming up with nice idea how to still solve a problem, not about knowing how to write scripts. I now had one idea and included Zsh solution in question.

Comment: Well if you're resourceful as you suggest, hinting you to use `shift` should get you on the right track.  It is available for both shells.

Answer (score 3):

Handle the (rest of the) arguments with a loop and `shift`. For `KEY=VALUE` type arguments, something like this (in bash):

```
function foo {
    shift      # handle the first "fixed" arg  
    while [ -n "$1" ] ; do
        key=${1%%=*}
        val=${1#*=}
        echo "key: $key value: $val"
        shift   
    done    
}              
foo first MYDATA=2 OTHERDATA=false
```

Or, you could use `getopts` (bash builtin) to parse `-x` style flags:

```
function bar {
    OPTIND=3   # skip first two args
    local opt
    while getopts "ab:" opt; do
        if [ "$opt" = "a" ] ; then
            echo flag -a encountered
        elif [ "$opt" = "b" ] ; then
            echo flag -b with arg $OPTARG
        fi
    done
}

bar fixed args -a -b foo
```